# Workbox webpack plugin doesn't generate serviceWorker

Tags: webpack, vue.js, service-worker, vue-cli, workbox

I am in development env.

I installed [cli-plugin-pwa](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa) that use [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin).
My `vue.config.js` file is very simple :

```js
// ...
  // 'GenerateSW' is the default workboxPluginMode
  pwa: {
    name: 'MyProject',
    themeColor: '#3C60BE',
    msTileColor: '#20AB72',
    workboxOptions: {
      swDest: './public/service-worker.js'
    }
  }
// ...
```

So workbox should generate a `service-worker.js` file in `./public` when I start the server but it doesn't.

Am I doint anything wrong ?

Comment: you need to choose a plugin mode: `workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',`
Here is a link to the docu: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa